# Yii2 - How to prevent bootstrap.js from being loaded twice?

Tags: php, yii2

I'm working on a site which is with yii\bootstrap\BootstrapAsset as a dependency in AppAsset.php

I also need to use flash messages which I'm using with this code:

```
if (Yii::$app->session->hasFlash('success'))
{
    echo \yii\bootstrap\Alert::widget([
        'options' => [
            'class' => 'alert-success',
        ],
        'body' => Yii::$app->session->getFlash('success'),
    ]);
}
```

However, whenever a flash message is triggered, when checking the console, bootstrap.js is loaded twice and messes up most of the functionalities on the site.

So: how can I prevent bootstrap.js from loading twice whenever a flash message is triggered?

[image: bootstrap.js loaded twice]

Comment: I think this is more of a javascript issue. You could modify `bootstrap.js` to include a `isOpen` variable. Combined with an `if statement` you should be able to stop the second script from running

Comment: I don't know. If I remove the code to display the flash message, everything works just fine and bootstrap.js is loaded only once.

Somehow, displaying a simple native Yii2 flash message is causing this script to be loaded a second time.